# I've got an error 404 while creating my new repository on Github. How to fix?

Tags: github, repository, web-hosting

This is my first time using Github to host my personal webpage. I've assumed that there is nothing wrong with my repository name which is tonyng.github.io, in which I've followed the format accurately.

However, there just seems to be an error whenever I tried to access the link through tonyng.github.io.

Here are my files for my webpage in this link : https://github.com/tonystaark/tonyng.github.io

Any advice?

Comment: Erm I guess no one knows the answer?

Answer (score 0):

So it seems to me that your username is tonystaark   but repo name is tonyng.github.io

According to the doc:

> If the first part of the repository doesn’t exactly match your
>   username, it won’t work, so make sure to get it right.

Comment: I changed it to (http://tonystaark.github.io) but it still won't show my webpage. It just shows 'http://tonyng.github.io'

Comment: At current time (commit 7b489468d58b67a5926aaf14d661b667fcb7896e ) looks like there are no files in the head commit on master branch, so hard to say exactly .